# LingPipe Named Entity Recognizer outputs a lot of mismatches

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition, lingpipe

I'm trying to extract named entities (people, persons and organizations) using LingPipe and following [this tutorial](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/ne/read-me.html). Here is the [full text](http://pastebin.com/YAUCWBMi) that I am trying to extract names from and here is the code (exception handling omitted for brevity):

```
Chunker chunker = readChunker("/path-to-chunker"); // custom method for
                                                     reading the model
String article = "Some long news article spanning multiple lines...";

Chunking chunking = chunker.chunk(article);
Set<Chunk> chunkingSet = chunking.chunkSet();
for (Chunk chunk : chunkingSet) {
   String name = article.substring(chunk.start(), chunk.end()));
   System.out.println(name);
}
```

And this is (part of) the output I get:

```
Tony Abbott
Indonesia
Joko Widodo
Sukumaran
Andrew Chan
Bali.
pair
the Bali
Nusa Kambangan
Indonesian
Indonesian
I’
Widodo. I
” Abbott
Julie Bishop
Widodo
al-Jazeera
Sukumaran
Chan
Bishop
”
```

As you can see, there are a lot of mismatches/partial matches like `Bali.`, `pair`, `the Bali`, `I'`, `Widodo. I`, `" Abbott`, `"`. I assume library's NER is working just fine and the problem is that the above code is somehow misusing the classes/methods from this library. But I just can't seem to find what is wrong about the code?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem is in the model of chunker that you read in the first line. Probably, it uses wrong tokenizer, which is the source of `Bali.`, `I'`, `Widodo. I`, `" Abbott`, `"`. 
`pair` and `the Bali` can be explained by ordinary errors (taggers usually have not more than 80-90% precision). However, the source of such errors can also be explained by bad model - for example, it can be trained for another domain.

Btw, why do you use longpipe, but not [Stanford NER](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml)? It shows better results, as a rule; e.g. the first available (i.e. random) [article](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1308/1308.0661.pdf). 
Also, [here](http://www.galalaly.me/index.php/2011/05/tagging-text-with-stanford-pos-tagger-in-java-applications/) is a good step-by-step tutorial for Standford NER.

Comment: Upvote for the research paper, since I am also testing several nlp libraries and this is very useful! This is also the reason for trying out LingPipe.

Comment: The model of the chunker is obtained from LingPipe's website, and it is pre-trained on the news articles corpus, which is exactly what I am testing it on. That is why I think it should perform much better than this.